# Finding the angle of a coordinate inside a circle

Tags: c++, math, directx, computational-geometry, trigonometry

Right down to business, basically I am making a small mini game which has characters running on top of a flat clock with the clock hand rotating around, the characters have to avoid it by jumping.
the part im struggling with is coding the collision, the clock hand is just a set model that is rotated applying matrices and for whatever reason box collision will not work.
So my theory is because i know the angle that the clock hand is currently being multiplied by, is there some mathematical way to calculate the angle of the player in relation to the centre point of the circle so that this can be checked against the clock hand angle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.

```
float angle = atan2(y_handle - y_center, x_handle - x_center);
```

Comment: Silly question possibly but what do you mean by handle and centre, the circles centre or the characters centre?

Comment: @Rex87 The center of the 'clock' you have. But draw it, think a bit (possibly get a highschook math book) and you'll see it instantly.

Comment: The centre is at point 0,0 so that makes it a tad easier, Thanks for the help :)